# Making two DIVs the same height

Tags: css

I would like to have the #textblock div to have at the same hight as #brevillestandard div.

CSS:

```
#textblock   {
     width: 260px;
     border: 1px solid #999999;
     padding: 0 5px;
     float: right;
     font-size: 95%; 
     background-color: #FEF4CC;

}

#brevillestandard   {
    padding: 8px 0 0 5px;
    height: 80px;
    Width: 61%;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is literally in the question.

You're giving `#brevillestandard` a height of 80px.

Add:

```
height: 80px;
```

to any other elements you want to be the same height.

Comment: Thanlk you, but i think i formulated the question itself quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are they not the same height when you set the `height` in the CSS for both of them?

Perhaps it's the different `padding` that is causing the difference in their appearance?

If you make the CSS identical, do the two `div`s look the same? That might be one place to start. Or apply the same CSS class to both, and see if they look the same then.